# Is the infimum condition wrong in this book?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the book I read it is written:

> ...Introducing definition of the infimum of bounded below set $X$ as the greates lower bound from all lower bounds, i.e.

> $$inf\space X = a \iff (\forall x \in X, a \leq x; \space \forall e>0 \space \exists x_e \in X:x_e<a-e)$$

Is it a typo, and there should be $x_e < a + e$?

Comment: Yes, "$+$" is correct.

Comment: I know, that definiton can't be false, so by "wrong" I mean that it is true, that mathematical expression is not equivalent to the plain words before it

Comment: @zkutch, thanks, and sorry for the question, that implies "yes" or "no" answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the plus sign. As it stands, it suggests there are elements of $X$ less than $a$, a contradiction. It looks like its trying to give two logically equivalent statements for an infimum. The first form I've seen as a definition, the second form, a corollary sometimes referred to as The Approximation Theorem.

Suppose $a = inf(X)$. Then by definition, $\forall x\in X\implies a \le x. If, \forall x \in X, b \le x \land b\ne a,$ then $b<a$. That is all other lower bounds of $X$ are less than $a$.

Approximation Theorem for the Infimum: Given an infimum of $X$, there exists $x\in X$ that approximates $inf (X)$ with arbitrary precision, i.e. $\forall \epsilon >0, a= inf(X), \exists x\in X, |x-a|\le \epsilon$. Proof:  Suppose we have $\epsilon_0$ for which the statement is untrue. That is, $a<a+\epsilon_0<x \forall x \in X$. Then $a+\epsilon_0$ is itself a lower bound which is greater than $a$, meaning $a$ is not a greatest lower bound, a contradiction. As a corollary, it follows that all bounded subsets of the integers contain their infimum and supremum.

Comment: I am preparing some new question, please be ready